# how filter {"foo":"bar", "bar": "foo"} with grok to get only foo field?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, logstash-grok, grok

I copied

```
{"name":"myapp","hostname":"banana.local","pid":40161,"level":30,"msg":"hi","time":"2013-01-04T18:46:23.851Z","v":0}
```

from https://github.com/trentm/node-bunyan and save it as my logs.json. I am trying to import only two fields (name and msg) to ElasticSearch via LogStash. The problem is that I depend on a sort of filter that I am not able to accomplish. Well I have successfully imported such line as a single message but certainly it is not worth in my real case.

That said, how can I import only name and msg to ElasticSearch? I tested several alternatives using http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ to reach an useful filter with no success at all.

For instance, %{GREEDYDATA:message} will bring the entire line as an unique message but how to split it and ignore all other than name and msg fields?

At the end, I am planing to use here:

```
input {
    file {
        type => "my_type"
        path => [ "/home/logs/logs.log" ]
        codec => "json"
    }   
}

filter {     

   grok {
            match => { "message" => "data=%{GREEDYDATA:request}"}        
        }   
#### some extra lines here probably
} 

output
{ 
  elasticsearch {
    codec => json
    hosts => "http://127.0.0.1:9200"
    index => "indextest"
  }

    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just gone through the list of [available Logstash filters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.2/filter-plugins.html). The [prune filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.2/plugins-filters-prune.html) should match your need.

Assume you have installed the [prune filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.2/plugins-filters-prune.html), your config file should look like:

```
input {
  file {
    type => "my_type"
    path => [ "/home/logs/logs.log" ]
    codec => "json"
  }
}

filter {
  prune {
    whitelist_names => [
      "@timestamp",
      "type",
      "name",
      "msg"
    ]
  }
} 

output { 
  elasticsearch {
    codec => json
    hosts => "http://127.0.0.1:9200"
    index => "indextest"
  }

  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Please be noted that you will want to keep `type` for Elasticsearch to index it into a correct type. `@timestamp` is required if you will view the data on [Kibana](https://www.elastic.co/products/kibana).